# what are sockets - uwsgi / nginx - django

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I am going through this tutorial http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

but i don't know what is the socket file, mysite.sock in this case.

Could you tell me what is this file and what should be inside ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

`.sock` files are the file sockets, used in [Unix domain socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket)

You just specific the path you want. When the server runs, the file is automatically created. (Read this [document](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#using-unix-sockets-instead-of-ports) for more information)